# Which sport uses the term "Butterfly Stroke"?

Tags: terminology

What sport uses the term "Butterfly Stroke"?

Comment: This is the first time I've seen someone post a question and then include the answer in the tags.

Comment: @F1Krazy that is because I've removed all the other tags the question does not belong to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [butterfly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_stroke) is a [swimming stroke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swimming_stroke), where both arms move symmetrically.

[image]